# Jscript CRM Return Value

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm, jscript

I am looking to pass a parameter from one function to another for example:

```
function getValueOfAttribute(field1Name) {
var attributeValue = Xrm.Page.getAttribute(field1Name).getValue();
return attributeValue;
}

function setFieldValue(field2Name, attributeValue) {
Xrm.Page.getAttribute(field2Name).setValue(attributeValue);
}
```

so if i called the first function passing it the field name parameter i want to then call the set function passing the second field name & the returned value from the get function

this is an example of the issue not the actual issue as i have more complex functions but still need to reference the return value.

ideally i want to but don't know if its possible to pass it in the comma separated list of parameters when adding a function.

Any ideas ?

Thank you

Comment: I'm not understanding what you're trying to do.  Why don't you write code that you'd like to be able to use when calling your two example functions.

Comment: Hi Daryl, the code needs to be dynamic based on the parameters not hard coded. for example if i had an onload function that returned a value i might want to then pass that value as a parameter to an onsave or on change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok with the help of glosrob(Thank you very much);

i Created a new function called JoinFunctions

```
 function JoinFunctions(Join)
 {
  var resultOfFunc =  Join;
 }
```

Calling this from form properties passing the parameter as

```
FunctionName1(Parameter1, FunctionName2(Parameter2, Parameter3))
```

For Example:

```
setFieldValue("fieldname", getFieldValue("firstname"))
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I follow, but...

> I am looking to pass a parameter from one function to another for example:

Well, that is as simple as:

```
function onLoad() {
    var resultOfFunc1 = doSomething();
    var resultOfFunc2 = doSomethingElse(resultOfFunc1);
}

function doSomething() {
    //do something
    return 1;
}

function doSomethingElse(param) {
    //do something involving param
    return 2;
}
```

Or even...

```
function onLoad() {
    var resultOfFunc2 = doSomethingElse(doSomething());
}

function doSomething() {
    //do something
    return 1;
}

function doSomethingElse(param) {
    //do something involving param
    return 2;
}
```

Comment: That's close :) thank you . How would it be constructed if i wanted to pass parameters to the first function or even pass the results of function 1 as a single parameter to the 2nd?

Comment: function onLoad() {
    var resultOfFunc1 = doSomething(parameter1, parameter2);
    var resultOfFunc2 = doSomethingElse(parameter3, resultOfFunc1, parameter4);
}   like this?